# How to get records which matches most to lesser criteria for user search?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, optimization

I know title is ambiguous, but what I want is to search products which matches exact criteria of user search and if there are no much records in that search, so I want to show other results along with users search result.

**Example: Suppose I have fields**

**productname    price     category      subcategory     startdate     enddate     name     city     state     country**

User can search from all of above fields but what I want user search should always gets to see at-least 12 result whether other results matches all criteria or not, means search should expand from exact match search to little loser(or may be no) match criteria.

I know I can achieve this easily through multiple queries but point is I want to achieve this with one query or fewer queries.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciable.

Comment: How many rows to search and how frequent a query are we talking about here, ie how well does it need to use indexes?

Comment: There would be multiple tables join but I have shown here fields on which search can be performed, rows count would go to thousands, and I don't want fire query multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a table scan is ok to get the result, the simplest way is most likely to just rank the rows by number of hits and show the 12 best ranking ones;

```
SELECT 
  *,
  CASE WHEN productname='prod#1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  ...
  CASE WHEN city='city#1'        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  ...
  CASE WHEN country='country'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END rank
FROM search
ORDER BY rank DESC
LIMIT 12
```

[An SQLfiddle example with just 3 columns implemented](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a10b8/2).

Comment: thanks it solves my problem, but will you tell me how much it will affect searching time?

Answer (score 1):

I think a two query can do this. First you run a query that matches the user criteria using a "=" sign and if no result was found, you then run another query using "LIKE".

```
Example

productname="searchcriteria"

and

productname %LIKE% "searchcriteria"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a limit 12 select from multiple unioned sub selects.  You'll need to decide the criteria match priority, e.g. matching product is more important than category therefore is higher in the select chain.

Basically:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE productname = <value> AND price = <value AND category = <value> AND subcategory = <value> AND startdate = <value> AND enddate = <value> AND name = <name> AND city = <value> AND state = <value> AND country = <value>
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE productname = <value>
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE price = <value>
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE category = <value>
     etc, etc
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM <table>
) LIMIT 12
```

This is a simplified example, you can adjust your union select criteria to taste, use OR's instead of AND's, change the order of the selects so that category matches are above price or whatever other changes you need.

Hope this helps some

Answer (score 0):

If you can achieve it with multiple queries write them and join by `UNION ALL`. Introduce an artificial column priority to define which results should be shown first.

```
select 1 as priority...
UNION ALL
select 2 as priority
UNION ALL
select 3 as priority
```

Then add `ORDER BY priority, <other necessary fields>`

and in the end `LIMIT 12` to leave desired amount of rows only